# Да но как сделать чтобы тексту эта полупрозрачность не применялась

Tags: html, hover, opacity

Как избавиться от затемнения текста.

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
li {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    padding: 14px 10px 21px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li:hover {
    background: #cfffa5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    /*color: #75ce66;*/
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Он не затемняется, а становится полупрозрачным.

Answer (score 3):

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
li {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    padding: 14px 10px 21px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li:hover {
    background: rgba(207, 255, 165, 0.5);
    /*color: #75ce66;*/
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
        <ul class="RightHeader__nav__ul">
         <li><a href="#">კატეგორიები</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">კონტაქტი</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ანგარიში</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: ну так я альфу в rgba задал)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте в место свойства `opacity` который изначальное задает прозрачность вашему фону и тексту, возможности свойства `background`, который предоставляет возможность задать цвет и прозрачность только фону.

```
li:hover { 
background: rgba(195,255,143,.5);
/*background: #cfffa5;*/
/*opacity: 0.5;*/
/*color: #75ce66;*/
font-size: 18px;
margin-bottom: -2px; 
}
```